# Add Line Chart in Plotly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, data-science, visualization

I am plotting buy and sell signals on a graph with plotly. I have successfully added the Buy and Sell signals. But how do I add a line chart for the price?

Here's my code I have taken random values:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()

x1=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
y1=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]

x2=[9,3,6,1,6]
y2=[7,2,56,25,22]

# Add traces
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x1, y=y1,
                    mode='markers',
                    name='Buy'))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x2, y=y2,
                    mode='markers',
                    name='Sell'))

fig.show()
```

[image]

But how do I add a line chart for the price?

Comment: Is it supposed to be different from what you've already done? Seems like you can copy and paste, just modifying "Scatter" to the name of the line plotting tool instead

Comment: If the price have the same x-axis, you can use add_trace.